# Memory card not detected

Tags: micro-sd-card

TL;DR

My microSD card is not been recognised/ detected by the GoPro 4, tablet or any pc and there's no sign of damage caused to the card. Is there a way to recover the data?

---

I was using a class 6 microSD card on my gopro 4 and kept on saying sd error after recording, usually anywhere from 45 second to 4 minutes and would stop recording. I would turn the gopro off and on again to start recording again and would do the same. I was on a family holiday and was the first time using the gopro and was thinking that the gopro was faulty.

The card is a 32gb and I pretty much dealt with the problem for about 5 days and continued recording/taking photos. During this time I was able to watch what I had recorded by inserting the microSD card on my tablet. But now the card is not been recognised/ detected by the gopro, tablet or any pc and there's no sign of damage caused to the card.

Is there a way to recover the data?

Comment: Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic (except when they interface with a computer). See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The problem originated in an off-topic device but the question is about recovering data from a microSD card, which would be done on a computer, which is on-topic.

Comment: I've heard of labs opening up the card and replacing the controller to access the data.  I suspect it would not be cost-effective for recovering holiday pictures.  If the card isn't recognized, you can't access what's on it.  It may be possible to reactivate the controller, but that wipes the card (and I wouldn't trust the card for reuse after failing).  Those cards do die and it sounds like yours has.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: If it's not detected by your system, then no.

---

MicroSD cards are incredibly difficult to recover data from if their external interface stops working - even the world's leading data recovery companies with direct endorsements from the manufacturer often can't do it.

Opening up cards and replacing controllers (as per fixer1234's comments) used to be feasible with full-size SD cards and SSDs but not MicroSD cards.

On rare occasions certain MicroSD cards have external pins that provide direct/debugging interfaces to the flash chips that can be utilized by data recovery specialists but as mentioned above, even that doesn't often work, and if it does, the costs run well into three to four digits.